# Radio buttons not submiting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".dist_radio").removeClass('dist_on');
        $(".dist_radio").children('input').attr('checked', false);
        $(this).addClass('dist_on');
        $(this).children('input').attr("checked", true);
    });
```

is the way I'm handling custom styled radio buttons and everything is fine if I click on a single radio (`#1`) and submit the form - it's being sent without errors (`note that I'm having my form submit in a new window`), if I chose another radio button (`#2`) and submit the form - again, the given radio is being sent with no issues, but if I then click back on the previously submitted radio button (`#1`), I get a validation error that I haven't chosen any radio button even though by checking the element with firebug, I can see that it has `checked="checked"` set.

Why is that and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @Anton well that sure was easy :) thanks!

Comment: @Anton provide this as an answer - not a comment. The poster all ready commented that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()` for property values

```
$(".dist_radio").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".dist_radio").removeClass('dist_on');
    $(".dist_radio").children('input').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).addClass('dist_on');
    $(this).children('input').prop("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition from one slide to the next is handled by your submitHandler, so the radio buttons need to do is submit the form on click, with that in mind:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled along with this issue and spent hours solving it. This is why:

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Better to post the content as an answer here. Links might be 404 in the future. Provide the link only as a reference.